# A single user on multiple chromebooks cannot use backspace

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook, google-workspace

We have 100+ chromebooks on site and one user (lets call them 'A') has an odd issue of that they cannot use backspace on any chromebook they log in to. The only way I have found that it could happen is if it is disable in the settings (which seems a bit odd to me). To my knowledge those settings are reset everytime a user logs into a chromebook and don't carry over. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you referring to the use of backspace while editing text or while navigating in the browser?

Comment: Might is be a matter of an extension?

Comment: Yes this is a matter of editing text anywhere on the device whilst A is logged in. Exstensions are locked down so no addtional one apart from ones we have vetted have been installed

Comment: `chrome://system` and `chrome://local-state` *might* hint at what’s wrong when comparing them to a healthy user profile.

Comment: It sounds as though all settings are synced for his account. So if there is a bad setting or bad extension, it is being copied to any other Chromebook they log in to.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out someone had used the Chromebook they were logged into and Re-binded the keys for backspace, escape, alt, and ctrl to random keys. Found it in Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard.
I appreciate everyone's help. And have learnt some new things on the way.

Comment: Great joke ! I'll remember that 8-)